# loading a .csv file to R

Tags: r, csv

I am learning R but I am stuck in loading my own dataset into R. So far, the code that I have is the following. The dataset (.csv) is located in my desktop.

```
Data500 <- read.csv("sp500.csv", header = TRUE)
```

I get this error message in the console.

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In file(file, "rt") :
> cannot open file 'sp500.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: Did you check the working directory of your RStudio project? You can check it with `getwd()`.

Comment: Try specifying the full file path instead of just “sp500.csv”

Answer (score 1):

This is because the file isn't located in your working directory, which is where R is searching.

use `getwd()` to see what working directory you are in currently (for this R session).

You can either

a) move your csv file to that working directory (if it happens to be a good place to keep it),

b) specify the full path (e.g., `read.csv("C:/Users/DChavez/Documents/Project_Name/sp500.csv")`)

OR

c) you can change the working directory to be where your file is before running `read.csv()`.

Two ways to do this:

1. Use `setwd()` at the top of your code to set the working directory. In Windows, it might look something like this: `setwd("C:/Users/DChavez/Documents/Project_Name/")`
2. IF you are using RStudio, you can navigate to the "Session" bar at the top, then "Set Working Directory" then "Choose Directory...", where you will navigate to the folder that houses your csv file.

Comment: I got it. The issue I was having was to correctly enter the path of the file into the code. This is the code I used to make it work. The file is in my desktop.

dataset <- read_csv("~/Desktop/sp500.csv")